# Asynctask and onclicklistener android 2.3.3 versus 3.2

Tags: android, onclick, android-asynctask

On my nexus One (android 2.3.3) the following program behaves differently from my xoom (android 3.2):

```
public class TestOnclickWithAsyncTask extends Activity {

private int mClicked = 0;

private final static String TAG = "TestOnclickWithAsyncTask";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.img_control_panel);

    final Button button = new Button(this);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mClicked++;
            Log.i (TAG, "Clicked "+ mClicked + " times");
        }
    });

    relativeLayout.addView(button);


    new LongTask().execute();

}

private class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

      protected void onPreExecute() {
      dialog = new  ProgressDialog(TestOnclickWithAsyncTask.this);
      dialog.setMessage("Waiting ");
      dialog.setIndeterminate(true); 
      dialog.setCancelable(true); 
      try {
          dialog.show();
      } catch (Exception e){}
      }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... notused) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep (30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//do long task
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void unusedg) { 
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.i (TAG,"Long task finished");
        }

}

}
```

On my Nexus I can't press the button while the asynctask is running (desired behavior):

```
09-26 00:45:34.361: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(3803): Long task finished
09-26 00:45:36.463: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(3803): Clicked 1 times
09-26 00:45:36.814: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(3803): Clicked 2 times
09-26 00:45:37.975: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(3803): Clicked 3 times
09-26 00:45:38.435: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(3803): Clicked 4 times
```

On my xoom I can just press the button and the progress indicator disappears.

```
09-26 00:49:05.440: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 1 times
09-26 00:49:06.230: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 2 times
09-26 00:49:06.580: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 3 times
09-26 00:49:06.840: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 4 times
09-26 00:49:08.170: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 5 times
09-26 00:49:08.560: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 6 times
09-26 00:49:30.960: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Long task finished 
09-26 00:49:32.800: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 7 times
09-26 00:49:33.810: INFO/TestOnclickWithAsyncTask(5887): Clicked 8 times
```

Why does this differ? And more importantly how can I prevent the xoom from canceling the progress dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `setCancelable(true)` when you don't want it to be that way? Maybe this will solve your issue...

Just a hint:

```
try {
    dialog.show();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

1. Why are you doing that?
2. Enclosing code in `try ... catch` with a general exception catch without a reaction is a really bad habit. When you do that you should always leave a comment with a good reason for that.

Comment: Or at least log the Exception so if it fails you know about it!

Comment: 1. Oops, removed the setCancelable (true), this didn't solve the issue though. 2. You are totally right, I should at least log the exception, but alas this didn't reveal anything either.

Comment: The dialog appears, you click the background (so the button) and dialog is dissmissed so you can click the button? Is this what happens? That would be really strange. (...sorry, I really have to catch sleep now, haven't slept all night)

Comment: Yup, that is what happens on my xoom (honeycomb 3.2)